# node deprecated warning while compiling less

Tags: css, node.js, less

When I use lessc to compile a less file, in the output CSS i always get as first line of the file this string:

```
(node) util.print is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
```

I googled the error but I don't understand if this is due to a nodejs error or a lessc one.

I tried also to run `lessc -s` but it didn't solve my issue.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Update. Less does not use `util.print` since `1.7.4` (released 2014-07-27).

Comment: `lessc -v` returns: `lessc 2.7.2`

Comment: Then this warning has nothing to do with `lessc` itself since it has no `util.print`. How exactly do you compile your files?

Comment: just typing lessc <filename> , i suppose you're right indeed, because i get the error even using silent mode.